# Hive - unable to compare two date columns in the same table

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am trying to compare two string columns that has date value in it.

Below is an example dataset

```
id start_dt   end_dt
1  2019-10-10 2019-10-10
2  2019-10-20 2020-01-01
3  2019-01-01 2020-01-01
```

I want to eliminate records where start_dt and end_dt are equal. I tried all the below inequality

```
select * from test where to_date(start_dt) <> to_date(end_dt)

select * from  test 
where to_date(from_unixtime(from_unixtimestamp(start_dt,'yyyy-mm-dd')))
  <>  to_date(from_unixtime(from_unixtimestamp(end_dt,'yyyy-mm-dd')))
```

But none of them worked for inequality where the same would work on equality.

Expected output

```
id start_dt   end_dt
2  2019-10-20 2020-01-01
3  2019-01-01 2020-01-01
```

any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

As you are having string type for the **`start_dt, end_dt`** columns and we can directly cast to **`date type(yyyy-MM-dd)`** and get only the non matching rows!

> **Try this query:**

```
select * from test where date(start_dt) <> date(end_dt);
```

We are simply casting to **`date type`** and comparing in where clause.